# How to retrieve standard object validation rules using eclipse or force.com migration toolkit

Tags: validation-rule, force.com-ide

I want to extract all standard and custom object validation rules in eclipse project so that i could search for specific strings which need to be replaced. I tried this but it did not work :

```
<types>
    <members>Case.*</members>
    <members>Account.*</members>
    <members>Opportunity.*</members>
    <members>Contact.*</members>
    <name>ValidationRule</name>
</types>


<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>ValidationRule</name>
</types>
```

I could find custom objects with validation rules using this :

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

but how do i get standard object validation rules in force.com project ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [the migration tool docs](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_migration_guide.pdf) (page 8 in the Summer 17 docs), you have to explicitly list standard objects to pick them up, and they go in the CustomObject section.  You can use alongside the wildcard for custom objects:

```
<types>
  <members>Case</members>
  <members>Account</members>
  <members>Opportunity</members>
  <members>Contact</members>
  <members>*</members>
  <name>CustomObject</name>
</types>
```

I believe (but cannot confirm at the moment) that validation rules will be included in the standard object files, just as they are for custom objects.